# Python - Getting around Beautifulsoup's "object has no attribute" error in empty page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

To extract the texts that I need, I am able to scrape most webpages using Beautifulsoup's **find_next_sibling** in my conditional execution.

```
if len(str(h4.find_next_sibling)) < 90:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

For one particular page, however, the webpage is empty so Python reports the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'

Since the empty page(s) seem to be produced by error in the list of pages I plan to scrape and I need Python to continue scraping without stopping at every similar instance, one possibility is to write a if condition to only run the code above when there is actually find_next_sibling in the page. Is it possible to do it? Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: how about `try: except:` ?

Comment: Hey thanks! I just tried to put "Try:" before the if statement and "except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError): coverage = "Empty page" " after the last line but there is still Syntax error.. can you be more specific?

Comment: @carl_pch https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: Thanks guys. It did not work for me the first time because I somehow capitalized T in try:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huge thanks to the commenters, this issue is successfully solved using **try: except**:

```
try: 
    if len(str(h4.find_next_sibling)) < 90:
        coverage = h4.find_next_sibling(text=True)
    else:
        if len(str(h4.find_next_sibling)[1]) < 90:
            coverage = h4.find_next_siblings(text=True)[2]
        else:
            coverage = h4.find_next_siblings(text=True)[1]
except:
    coverage = "Empty page"
```